# Rolling mean using groupby of two columns with window size of variable length in

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I want to calculate the rolling mean of modal_price grouped by (APMC,Commodity) for each year with window_length as no. of months of that year . According to my solution I'm getting all Nan's . The dataset is as follows :

```
              APMC |   Commodity  | qtl _weight| min_price | max_price | modal_price | district_name | Year | Month
date
2014-12-01  Akole   bajri            40              1375        1750      1563          Ahmadnagar  2014   12
2014-12-01  Akole   paddy-unhusked   346             1400        1800      1625          Ahmadnagar  2014   12
2014-12-01  Akole   wheat            55              1500        1900       1675         Ahmadnagar  2014   12
2014-12-01  Akole   bhagar/vari      59              2000        2600       2400         Ahmadnagar  2014   12
2014-12-01  Akole   gram              9              3200        3300       3235         Ahmadnagar  2014   12
2014-12-01  Jamkhed cotton           44199           3950        4033       3991         Ahmadnagar  2014   12
2014-12-01  Jamkhed bajri            846             1300        1488       1394         Ahmadnagar  2014   12
2014-12-01  Jamkhed wheat(husked)    155             1879        2231       2055         Ahmadnagar  2014   12
2014-12-01  Kopar   gram             421             1983        2698       2463         Ahmadnagar  2014   12
2014-12-01  Kopar   greengram         18             6734        7259       6759         Ahmadnagar  2014   12
2014-12-01  Kopar   soybean          1507            2945        3247       3199         Ahmadnagar  2014   12
2016-11-01  Sanga   wheat(husked)    222             1730        2173       1994         Ahmadnagar  2016   11
```

There are 60k rows with each APMC,Commodity cluster having different no. of months for three years (2014,2015,2016) .

Comment: Could you just break into different dfs for each year?

Comment: Still getting Nan's . And how do i account for variable window_size ? i.e the no. of months present in the dataset for that year ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to form groups for each year x APMC x Commodity and then use `.expanding().mean()` to calculate the rolling mean for each group. Since your data appears to be monthly, this will be a rolling mean every month.

### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2014-11-01','2014-11-01','2014-11-01',
                            '2014-12-01','2014-12-01','2014-12-01',
                            '2015-01-01','2015-01-01','2015-01-01'],
                   'APMC': np.tile(['Akole', 'Jamkhed', 'Kopar'], 3),
                   'Commodity': np.tile(['wheat', 'cotton', 'gram'], 3),
                   'modal_price': np.random.randint(1000,2000,9)})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df = df.set_index('Date')

#               APMC Commodity  modal_price
#Date                                      
#2014-11-01    Akole     wheat         1510
#2014-11-01  Jamkhed    cotton         1365
#2014-11-01    Kopar      gram         1382
#2014-12-01    Akole     wheat         1322
#2014-12-01  Jamkhed    cotton         1988
#2014-12-01    Kopar      gram         1098
#2015-01-01    Akole     wheat         1742
#2015-01-01  Jamkhed    cotton         1017
#2015-01-01    Kopar      gram         1595
```

### Code

```
df = df.sort_index()
df.assign(Year=df.index.year).groupby(['Year', 'APMC', 'Commodity']).modal_price.expanding().mean()
```

### Output

```
Year  APMC     Commodity  Date      
2014  Akole    wheat      2014-11-01    1510.0
                          2014-12-01    1416.0
      Jamkhed  cotton     2014-11-01    1365.0
                          2014-12-01    1676.5
      Kopar    gram       2014-11-01    1382.0
                          2014-12-01    1240.0
2015  Akole    wheat      2015-01-01    1742.0
      Jamkhed  cotton     2015-01-01    1017.0
      Kopar    gram       2015-01-01    1595.0
Name: modal_price, dtype: float64
```

Since the output has the index of the original `DataFrame` you can join the results if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you NEED to do grouping but you could just do:

```
out = {}
for APMC_ in df.APMC.unique():
   for Commodity_ in df.Commodity.unique():
       for year_ in set(df.index.year):

           temp = df[(df.APMC==APMC_) & (df.Commodity==Commodity_) & (df.index.year==year_) ].copy()

           n_months = temp.shape[0]...

           out[APMC_ + Commodity_ + str(year)] = temp.mean() # or whatever
```

but after typing this i feel your "number of months in that year" bit might be ill posed.

anyway, this isn't EXACTLY what you asked for, but solves your question.

Comment: Can't stop running . As I said there are 60k rows , the code is taking forever to execute